Run TeamCity whole build chain of project A when build of project B finishes
This is my scenario of builds in teamcity:
Project A:
A1 <- A2 <- A3 (Snapshot dependency)

Project B:
B1

Every build in project A has snapshot dependency on the previous one, with this checkbox marked:
Do not run new build if there is a suitable one.
It's important to mention that I can't change this, this checkbox must be marked.
I want that when build B1 finishes, project A build chain will run in the following order:
A1 then A2 then A3.
With the checkbox this does not work, I tried to have Trigger configuration in build A3 of Finish Build Trigger on build B1, but what happened is that only build A3 ran because of the checkbox Do not run new build if there is a suitable one.
Is there a way to achieve this without unmarking the checkbox?
Thanks

Have you tried adding a Finish Build Trigger to build configuration A1, referencing build configuration B1?
If you also have equivalent triggers in A2 (for when A1 finishes) and A3 (for when A2 finishes) - which are probably already in place - then this should allow the full build chain to execute in order.
